# Defining Dedekind cut multiplication without absolute value function.

Tags: logic, set-theory

I'm working through Classic Set Theory by Goldrei. The text works with Dedekind left sets as reals and gives the following definition:

If $\mathbf{r}>_{\mathbb{R}}\mathbf{0}$ then the product of $\mathbf{r}$ and $\mathbf{s}$ is defined as follows:
$$\mathbf{r} \cdot_{\mathbb{R}}  \mathbf{s}=\begin{cases}
\left\{p \cdot_{\mathbb{Q}} q: p \in \mathbf{r}, p>_{\mathbb{Q}} 0 \text { and } q \in \mathbf{s}, q>_{\mathbb{Q}} 0\right\}\cup\{q \in \mathbb{Q}: q \leq_{\mathbb{Q}} 0\}, & \text { if } \mathbf{s}>_{\mathbb{R}} \mathbf{0}, \\
\{p \cdot_{\mathbb{Q}} q: p \notin \mathbf{r} \text { and } q \in \mathbf{s}\}, & \text { if } \mathbf{s} \leq_{ \mathbb{R}} \mathbf{0}.
\end{cases}  (*)$$

I'm comfortable proving that this product is a Dedekind left set. Exercise 2.8 asks:
Give the definition of $\mathbf{r} \cdot_{\mathbb{R}}  \mathbf{s}$ for $\mathbf{r} \leq_{\mathbb{R}}  \mathbf{0}$ and any $\mathbf{s}$. My attempt is:

$$\mathbf{r}\cdot_{\mathbb{R}}\mathbf{s}\begin{cases}
\{p\cdot_{\mathbb{Q}}q:p\in\mathbf{r}\mbox{ and } q\notin\mathbf{s}\}, & \mbox{ if }\mathbf{s}>_{\mathbb{R}}\mathbf{0},\\
\{p\cdot_{\mathbb{Q}}q:p\notin\mathbf{r},\enspace p<_{\mathbb{Q}}0\mbox{ and } q\notin\mathbf{s},\enspace q<_{\mathbb{Q}}0\}\cup\{q\in\mathbb{Q}:q\leq_{\mathbb{Q}}0\}, & \mbox{ if }\mathbf{s}\leq_{\mathbb{R}}\mathbf{0}.
\end{cases} $$

I'm having trouble proving that the last case (both non-positive) is a Dedekind left set. I suspect the problem is with my definition. Does it not work?

For context: I know that other texts define the positive case and then use absolute value for the others. But $(*)$ includes a negative case without absolute value. The text has not mentioned the function yet. So I think the answer needs to be in set builder notation.

P.S. I'm new here. This is my first question!

Comment: Hint: we want $-x \cdot y = -(x \cdot y)$. Try using that idea to check your answer or to give an alternative to your answer.

Comment: Thanks @RobArthan. I think now I need to modify my last case so that all inequalities are strict. Otherwise, if rational 0 is always in the set, then it can never produce the 0 cut with that definition.